# Change in Arc Position as Trainer Gains Levels

Tags: pokemon-go

I trained a Pidgeot to nearly full completion of its arc (~90%) and then stopped training for a while due to a lack of stardust and the game saying my trainer level wasn't high enough. While collecting more dust, I gained at least four levels (the minimum four were due to a powerleveling push with a lucky egg). I then when to check on my Pidgeot again to see if I could power it up further, and its position on the arc now lines up around three-quarters (75%) of arc completion. The stardust/candies cost for the next power-up hasn't changed.

I know this is an odd question, but has anyone noticed the CP range that the arc is supposed to indicate a pokemon can train through move or change due to gains in trainer level?

I know that gaining trainer levels allows a person to catch stronger pokemon (or pokemon with more potential strength), but does gaining trainer levels also allow previously caught pokemon to be trained to higher levels?

I wish I had pictures to back up this question, but I didn't think this was possible until I noticed this discrepancy. I'm now starting a test for this by taking pictures of pokemon to record any changes while not being trained as I gain levels, but I feel a little crazy for thinking this could be a thing.

Comment: Yes, this is a thing.

Comment: Working as intended. Is there a more specific question you have about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you train your Pokémon high enough, it will get to the stage where you will get a notification saying

> "Trainer is not a high enough level to train this Pokémon"

meaning that the Pokémon has reached it's max CP for your current Trainer level. The CP meter may not be 100% full, but it is at a stage where the increase in CP will exceed this meter. Eg. Training a Pokémon raises the CP by 20, and the meter is at 85/100.

Raising your Trainer level will increase this meter, allowing you to train your Pokémon to a higher level.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, raising your trainer level increases the max CP that you can train a Pokemon to.

Answer (score 3):

Pokemon have a **hidden level** stat. The arc is a ratio between the Pokemon's hidden level vs the maximum level.

When you as a trainer level up, the maximum level for that Pokemon increases; thus lowering your ratio, and lowering the arc's position.